# I am not able to get the permission of Storage for read and write in xamarin form

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-permissions

My App i am trying to get storage permission for read and write. I used the below code for solution but i am not able to get the permission popup and i am always getting Xamarin.Essentials.PermissionStatus.Denied as a result. I am using VS 2022 and Target Android version is 14.

Permission Interface (IReadWritePermission):

```
public interface IReadWritePermission
{        
    Task<PermissionStatus> CheckStatusAsync();
    Task<PermissionStatus> RequestAsync();
}
```

Permission Usage in Share Code:

```
var readWritePermission = DependencyService.Get<IReadWritePermission>();
var status = await readWritePermission.CheckStatusAsync();
if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
{
    status = await readWritePermission.RequestAsync();
}
```

Android Code

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

    [assembly:Dependency(typeof(ReadWriteStoragePermission))]
    
    namespace ATSDriver.Droid
    {
        public class ReadWriteStoragePermission :  Xamarin.Essentials.Permissions.BasePlatformPermission, IReadWritePermission
        {
            public override (string androidPermission, bool isRuntime)[] RequiredPermissions => new List<(string androidPermission, bool isRuntime)>
            {
                (Android.Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage, true),
                (Android.Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage, true)
            }.ToArray();
    
            public async Task<PermissionStatus> CheckStatusAsync()
            {
                return await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<ReadWriteStoragePermission>();
            }
    
            public async Task<PermissionStatus> RequestAsync()
            {
                return await Permissions.RequestAsync<ReadWriteStoragePermission>();
            }
        }
    }
```

MainActivity.cs

```
DependencyService.Register<IReadWritePermission, ReadWriteStoragePermission>();
```

**Option 2**

*Direct in Shared Code : -*

```
var statusSto = await Xamarin.Essentials.Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();
if (statusSto != Xamarin.Essentials.PermissionStatus.Granted)
{
    statusSto = await Xamarin.Essentials.Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();
}
```

Thanks for your reply and solutions

Comment: You can check this Android document about [Granular media permissions](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions). You need to use the new permissions instead of using the ReadExternalStorage.

Answer (score 0):

If your app targets Android 13 or higher and needs to access media files that other apps have created, you must request one or more of the following granular media permissions instead of the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission: `READ_MEDIA_IMAGES`, `READ_MEDIA_VIDEO`, `READ_MEDIA_AUDIO`.

You can change the permission code in this class.

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

    [assembly:Dependency(typeof(ReadWriteStoragePermission))]
    
    namespace ATSDriver.Droid
    {
        public class ReadWriteStoragePermission :  Xamarin.Essentials.Permissions.BasePlatformPermission, IReadWritePermission
        {
            public override (string androidPermission, bool isRuntime)[] RequiredPermissions => new List<(string androidPermission, bool isRuntime)>
            {
                (Android.Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage, true),
                (Android.Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage, true)
            }.ToArray();
    
            public async Task<PermissionStatus> CheckStatusAsync()
            {
                return await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<ReadWriteStoragePermission>();
            }
    
            public async Task<PermissionStatus> RequestAsync()
            {
                return await Permissions.RequestAsync<ReadWriteStoragePermission>();
            }
        }
    }
```